# Error installing packing on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, dependencies

I'd like to install `libjbig-dev` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. So I run

```
sudo apt-get install libjbig-dev
```

which returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjbig-dev : Depends: libjbig0 (= 2.0-2ubuntu4) but 2.0-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I do

```
sudo apt-get install libjbig0
```

which returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libjbig0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Now what? How can I install libjbig-dev? Thanks.

Comment: Try these `sudo apt-get clean && apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f` and try again to install that lib.

Comment: Thanks. I did it and got
    `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)`
    `E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/`
    `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)`
    `E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`

Comment: Close software center, Synaptic if you use them. If it still doesn't work, reboot and try again.

Comment: Would you please explain? I am running these command in a console? How should I close software center Synaptic?